# REST sobjects, how get owner.name instead of owner.id

Tags: rest-api, rest

Do you know if it's possible to get owner.name instead of owner.id via

```
services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Entity?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query like this way:

```
/services/data/v41.0/query/?q=SELECT+Owner.Name+FROM+Case+LIMIT+10
```

Refer [Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Specify the "fields" parameter:

```
/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Account/001500000154s0CAAQ?fields=Owner.Name
```

You can specify multiple fields with commas, all fields supported by SOQL will work here (so, up to five levels deep in relationships).

Output Example:

```
{
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "Account",
    "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Account/001500000154s0CAAQ"
  },
  "Owner" : {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "User",
      "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/User/00550000000wTdSAAU"
    },
    "Name" : "Brian Fear"
  },
  "Id" : "001500000154s0CAAQ"
}
```

Comment: what is the better approach? SOQL or Entity fields?

Comment: @SantanuBoral Both methods are viable, though one saves you writing a query when you already know the Id. I'd personally use Entity when possible; it's basically shorthand for writing the query, and returns a slightly less dense JSON object. You can use whichever you prefer. Obviously, if you don't know the ID, or need multiple records, you'd prefer a query.

Comment: all other fields are excluded, is it possible included them +extra fields like owner.name?

Comment: @AndrewG Nope. Either all fields, or specify your own, as far as I can tell. Which is kind of unfortunate. You can still call a describe, get all the fields, then use the Entity resource to get the record; it's still slightly easier than using SOQL, if you ask me.